# Matrix property formal name

Tags: matrices, terminology

With matrices, we often stack up names that describe what properties they have. I am searching for the name of the property shared by:

- Adjacency matrices
- Currency exchange matrices
- Stochastic matrices

which is that they are read/traversed row to column.

What terminology do I use to convey concisely that this is how a matrix is intended to be read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all your cases you are working with matrices constructed from connections of graphs. For example, the stochastic matrix is a set of probabilities that you transition from one connected state to another, and a currency exchange matrix is built with the connection from exchanging one currency to another with a weight of the exchange rate.

As such I would say that all of these matrices are types of **adjacency matrices** or **transition matrices**. In the example of currency exchange or stochastic matrices you would have a **weighted adjacency matrix**. Maybe there is a more formal term, but that is what I would use to communicate these things.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will wait a while to see if there are any alternatives before accepting this answer.